# NodeJS BookShelf App OAuth 2.0 (Authenticating Users section) not working

Tags: node.js, cloud, google-oauth, platform

As the heading suggests, I am going through the NodeJS BookShelf App tutorial (in the Authenticating Users section) on google cloud platform.  I have generated an OAuth Client ID Web Application Key and input the redirect URI's exactly in the app as well as in the config.json file locally.  Whenever I try to login in the app, it holds for about a minute then redirects to a page that says "Something Broke!". In the browser console it reported internal server error 500.

Has anyone had this problem before?

Why is it not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this stage of the tutorial as well.  The "MEMCACHE_URL" environment variable defined in 'config.js' defaulted to "127.0.0.1:11211" -- replacing "127.0.0.1" with "memcache" (ie "memcache:11211") resolved the issue for me.

[This github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/issues/123) provided the necessary hint.