# NodeJS Bookshelf App tutorial create config.json file with content

Tags: google-app-engine

I am following the NodeJS Bookshelf app tutorial on google cloud platform. It says we should create a config.json file in the nodejs-getting-started/2-structured-data directory and fill it with

```
{
  "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]",
  "DATA_BACKEND": "cloudsql",
  "MYSQL_USER": "nodejsapp",
  "MYSQL_PASSWORD": "[YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD]",
  "MYSQL_HOST": "[YOUR_MYSQL_HOST]"
}
```

I am using the cloud shell provided by google and I am having a hard time filling in the content. I have tried to open the .json off google's cloud to enter the content with sublime and it's not possible.

I followed this question 
[NodeJS BookShelf App OAuth 2.0 (Authenticating Users section) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38127005/nodejs-bookshelf-app-oauth-2-0-authenticating-users-section-not-working)
and it's way ahead of where I am currently. Anyone worked on this tutorial before? How did you create the config.json file and fill in the content?

Comment: the file is in cloud - so sublime wont work? Try 
vi config.json - if you have not used vi before you can have a look at http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi.html

Comment: Thanks. I was able to use vim to enter the son file. There is help for vim use at linuxconfig.org